# Octave parsing error

Tags: matlab, octave

I making a basic bisection code, but a taking an error as:

```
    >> asdfg

parse error near line 22 of file C:/Octave/Octave-4.2.1/bin\asdfg.m

  syntax error
```

my code is :

```
    a = [1 -9 -2 120 -130]

x0=1
x1=2
e=0,0132

while abs(x0-x1)/2 > e
  gcc = (x0+x1)/2;
  if polyval(a,x0)*polyval(a,gcc) < 0
    x1=gcc;

  else if polyval(a,x1)*polyval(a,gcc) < 0
    x1=gcc;

  else
    printf("asfd")
    end
  end
```

BTW i made the code like matlab syntax as i know. I just know they are same syntax.

Comment: It would help if you indented your code properly. The two `end` at the bottom are not aligned with what they’re ending.

Answer (score 2):

```
else if polyval(a,x1)*polyval(a,gcc) < 0
```

should be

```
elseif polyval(a,x1)*polyval(a,gcc) < 0
```

No space between `else` and `if` in MATLAB/Octave.